# How to analyse Directionality (like Fiji Tool) in Matlab? Imgradient function does not work

Tags: image-processing, matlab

I am just starting to use Matlab, so sorry in advance if my mistake is "silly".
My objective is to be able to analyse the direction of tubes/fibers/stripes in a greyscale (8bit) image. Example: See this picture:

http://www.mediachance.com/dvdlab/helppro2/transitionbmp.jpg

When I use the Fiji Directionality Tool, the direction of the signal returned is: 0º, which is an expected value (taking only a range from 0º to 180º).

The script I am trying to write should lead to a similar result to the one I get in Fiji.
To this end, I used the imgradient function from the Matlab Image Processing Toolbox (2013).

### Here is the script:

```
enter code here

clear all;
close all;
p = 0;

a = imread('image.tif');

%Apply the imgradient function

[M D] = imgradient(a);
[r c] = size(a);

%Given that I get directions in [-180 to 180] I transform the negatives in the      corresponding positives (e.g.: -45 = 135)

for x = 1 : c;
for y = 1 : r;
    if D(x,y) < 0;
        d_nonnegatives(x,y) = D(x,y) + 180;
    else
        d_nonnegatives(x,y) = D(x,y);
    end;
end;
end;

% Prepare the date to make the graphs

for x = 1 : c;
for y = 1 : r;
p = p + 1;
d_list(p) = d_nonnegatives(x,y);   
end;
end;

d_list_transposed = d_list';
d_list_sorted = sortrows(d_list_transposed);
binrange = [0:10:180];
[N bins] = histc(d_list_sorted,binrange);

%Make figures

figure, imshow(D), title('Image Direction Matrix')
figure, hist(d_list_sorted,binrange), title('Amount of Pixels vs Direction: Negative      values converted to positive');
figure, hist(D), title('Amount of Pixels vs Direction: Values non-converted to positive');
```

---

The result I get from this script from the last histogram:"Amount of Pixels vs Direction: Values non-converted to positive" is: approximately 90ºC. This value is perpendicular to the one I should obtain, which is as I mentioned before, 0ºC (Fiji Directionality Tool).

However, With this script I can get the right direction when the picture I analyse is plain.
Like in the following link:

http://www.wuphonsreach.org/Games/SimCity4/HbgPA/24x16_GradientHeighMap.png

In this case, the script returns the direction I expected (Fiji=Matlab script=90º). However when I have "stripes" or "tubes" of signal aligned in a certain direction, the value which is returned is according to my interpretation the one of the highest change of signal (stripes vs. background), thereby the one perpendicular to the direction of the stripes. This is not what I need.

What I really need is a script that returns the direction of the stripes of the signal.

I hope I was clear enough. Please do not hesitate to contact me to ask me more questiones.

And many many many thanks!!!!!!!!!!!

All the best,

Juan.-